# How to get attribute value from li tag in python BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get the src attribute of this link tag with BS4 library?

Right now I'm using the code below to achieve the resulte but i can't

```
<li class="active" id="server_0" data-embed="<iframe src='https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=757563422&id=456240701&hash=1d8fcd32c5b5f28b' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true' ></iframe>"><a><span><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span> <strong>vk</strong></a></li>
```

i want this value src='https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=757563422&id=456240701&hash=1d8fcd32c5b5f28b'

this my code i access ['data-embed'] i don't how to exract the link this my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
access = "https://w.mycima.cc/play.php?vid=d4d8322b9"
response = scraper.get(access)
doc2 = bs(response.content, "lxml")
container2 = doc2.find("div", id='player').find("ul", class_="list_servers list_embedded col-sec").find("li")
link = container2['data-embed']
print(link)
```

Result

```
<Response [200]>
https://w.mycima.cc/play.php?vid=d4d8322b9
<iframe src='https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=757563422&id=456240701&hash=1d8fcd32c5b5f28b' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true' ></iframe>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the beautiful soup documentation

> You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a
> dictionary

They give the example:

```
tag = BeautifulSoup('<b id="boldest">bold</b>', 'html.parser')
tag['id']
# 'boldest'
```

Reference and further details,
see: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

So, for your case specifically, you could write

```
print(link.find("iframe")['src'])
```

if `link` turns out to be plain text, not a soup object - which may be the case for your particular example based on the comments - well then you can resort to string searching, regex, or more beautiful soup'ing, for example:

```
link = """<Response [200]>https://w.mycima.cc/play.php?vid=d4d8322b9<iframe src='https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=757563422&id=456240701&hash=1d8fcd32c5b5f28b'></iframe>"""
iframe = re.search(r"<iframe.*>", link)
if iframe:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(iframe.group(0),"html.parser")
    print("src=" + soup.find("iframe")['src'])
```

Comment: already do that but i get this error <Response [200]>
https://w.mycima.cc/play.php?vid=d4d8322b9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unssl\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\cima2023.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(link['src'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: no this not all my code where I can send you all my code

Comment: but this the part where I have a problem the other code has no relation it's works fine

Comment: okay, I've adjusted my answer. You still need to search for the iframe in what you already found, as it still nested inside the result you found previously, but you still haven't gotten "down" to the just the tag that has the `src` attribute. Put another way, you aren't looking for just an `li` tag, but for an `iframe` tag nested inside an `li` tag.

Comment: not working I think I found the problem the result of the link variable is a string when I treat it like a string I got the response

Comment: print(link[12:64])    C:\Users\unssl\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/unssl/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/cima2023.py
<Response [200]>
'https://vidspeed.cc/embed-g5cbf9ssfazb.html' scroll

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: i think it is impossible to get the link

Comment: okay, you can try this too: `print(BeautifulSoup(link).find("iframe")['src'])` Or other string searching strategies - or if you feel it is safe and the string will always be exactly the same, just going by position as in your solution print(["link[12:64])".

Comment: I've posted more to my solution. Do not think it is impossible. This is not the way of the coder.

Comment: ohhh well done it's work like magic i add only "lxml"

Comment: wp play bro and also i use strip() to remove all irrelevant content let only your but ur solution is nice

Comment: I will try your solution in for loop and see if it's work without any problems thank you so much